# PHP - write to CSV issue

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

Read from a csv file and pick certain columns and write again to another csv file. Everything fine except that the last column is always get wrap around with a pair of double quotes and the last double quotes is in a new line, which is strange. Below is my code and the output

```
if( file_exists($file_path) && filesize($file_path) > 0){
      $counter = 0;
      if(false !== ($read_file = fopen($file_path,'r')) ){
        $output_file = fopen($file_output,'w');
        while(false !== ($data = fgetcsv($read_file))){
          $outputData = array($data[1], $data[6], $data[19]);
          fputcsv($output_file, $outputData,',');
        }

      }
      fclose($read_file);
      fclose($output_file);
      unset($outputData);

    }

Output: data1,data6,"data9
 "
```

Yes, so the last double quotes is in the newline and the last column is wrapped with a double quotes regards of what the data type is.

Thank you very much

Comment: You can use `trim()` function to trim $data while filling up $outputData array.
             `$outputData = array(trim($data[1]), trim($data[6]), trim($data[19]));`

Comment: Is your only problem that it looks strange? .csv files don't always look great. The quotes are there because there are newline characters in that last columns data. Without them there would be no way to represent the new line.

Comment: Ugur it doesnt work .. I've just tried .. Phil_1984_ yes it is so strange .. will spend sometime to read different file or something

Comment: You may have some weird data in that column then. You could try using bin2hex to see exactly what it is.

Comment: i have also make a custom column which auto increment when each row added and appended it into the file. The new column is also wrap with double quotes like above. The original data is also in proper format